# Duplicate query logs with Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: logback, spring-data-mongodb, spring-logback, logback-classic

My application.yml:

```
 logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate: DEBUG
```

And in logs I see two records lilke this:

```
2021-10-27 12:06:14.014 DEBUG 30540 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : findOne using query: { "id" : "2"} fields: Document{{}} for class: class com.victorlevin.StockService.domain.User in collection: users
2021-10-27 12:06:14.015 DEBUG 30540 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : findOne using query: { "_id" : "2"} fields: {} in db.collection: TestDB.users
```

I've found that class MongoTemlate has two places with logs:
`doFindOne()` and `FindOneCallback()`

How can I restrict logging one of these methods? Maybe how to set logging level on a method of a class?